# How to refresh the jQuery .each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Explaining by example:

```
$(selector).each(function () {
    if (expression) {
        $(this).next().remove();
    }
    ....
});
```

Based on an `expression` I remove an element that also are a part of the `selector`, and in effect are removing the next element the `.each()` function will get.

The `.each()` function doesn't seem to care and are running it's code on the removed element breaking the iteration process on my code in the each function. Basically meaning a counter in the `.each()` function will count the deleted element even though it shouldn't.

Is there a way to refresh or update the `.each()` function so it skips elements that where removed after its initiation?

Answer (score 2):

Better to [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) your elements before:

```
$(selector).filter(function() {
  if (expression) {
    return false;
  }
}).each(function() { .. });
```

I do not think you can modify the collection from **inside** the `each` call.

Even better, you can split this in two calls, since if you do all of it in one call only, the selector will be cached:

```
$(selector).filter(function() {
  return expression;
}).next().remove();

// and then

$(selector).each(function() { ... }); // now *without* removed elements.
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to remove the element from the DOM, not remove it from the .each() function - so a filter won't help. I'm now thinking about running the each function twice btw.

Comment: @Espen What's wrong there: `$(selector).filter(function() {
    return expression;
}).next().remove();`??? In fact, can you provide sample showing expected behaviour? I'm not sure why you couldn't just filter it

Comment: I need to remove the next element if an attribute match the current element - the effect I get is that no two matching elements are next to each other. In a list this can be the start of a group, if two starts are next to each other then a group is empty and can be removed. I don't know of any filter that can do that. The problem at hand is not to get anything filtered, but how to deal with an element in the .each() function being removed from the DOM after initialization.

Comment: My point is, I do not think you can update the DOM **and** the collection at the same time. First update the DOM, then get the collection again.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you query the DOM with `$(selector)` you are given back a jQuery collection containing all the elements (specifically, references to the elements) that satisfy that selector. Any changes to the DOM do not affect that collection. If you happen to modify the DOM in such a way that the elements in the collection no longer satisfy the initial selector, this will not be reflected.

The correct solution to this problem is to not modify the DOM in the each loop, and basically find another way to solve your problem. But a simple (computationally expensive) solution is just to recheck the element on the initial selector upon iteration... you can use the `.is` method to achieve this:

```
$(selector).each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(selector)) {
        if (expression) {
            $this.next().remove();
        }
    }
    ....
});
```